# Finding measurable sets given a set function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on the following question:

Let $\mu : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to [0,\infty]$ be defined by $\mu(E) = \frac{n}{1+n}$ if $|E|=n$ and $\mu(E)=1$ if $|E|=\infty$

I've begun by trying to show that $\mu$ is an outer measure and then my aim was to use the Caratheodory definition of measurable sets to find the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu$-measurable sets.

I'm stuck on showing that $\mu$ is countably monotone. I'm also interested if there is a general way to approach these sorts of "Determine the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets" type questions. Every time I work on one it feels like a piecemeal process. Is there a sort of "algorithmic" way to complete these type of problems?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning countable monotony, let $(E_n)$ be an increasing sequence of subsets of $\mathbb N$, and let $E = \bigcup_n E_n$.

If $|E| = \infty$, then for all $n$, there's some $N$ such that $|E_N| \geq n$, which, because the sequence of sets is increasing, implies that $|E_m| \geq n$ for all $m \geq N$. This implies that for all $\epsilon > 0$, and all sufficiently large $n$,
$$\mu(E_n) \geq \frac{n}{n+1} > 1-\epsilon.$$
In other words, $\lim_n \mu(E_n) = 1 = \mu(E).$

If $|E| = c < \infty$, then for some $N$ and all $n \geq N$, $E_n = E$. Thus,
$$\lim_n \mu(E_n) = \frac{c}{c+1} = \mu(E).$$

Concerning the last question: sorry, I don't know of an algorithm for solving extension problems in measure theory (if you discover one, please let me know!). However, if you post exactly what parts of your problem you're stuck on, you might get some helpful tips.

---

**Added.** Above I guessed at the meaning of "countably monotone," but you have since clarified the definition you have in mind in the comments. Here's a different argument.

Let $(E_n)$ be any countable covering of $E$. The result is immediate if $E$ is empty, so assume it's not. Note that $\mu(A) \geq 1/2$ for all nonempty $A \subseteq \mathbb N$. So if $E_n$ is nonempty for infinitely many $n$, then $\sum_{n}\mu(E_n) = \infty$, and the result follows. So assume that $E_n$ is empty for all but finitely many $n$, and call the nonempty ones $E_{k_1},...,E_{k_N}$. Thus, $\sum_n \mu(E_n) = \sum_{i=1}^N \mu(E_{k_i})$.

Now, if $|E| = \infty$, then for $|E_{k_i}| = \infty$ for some $i \in \{1,...,N\}$ too (because $E_{k_1},...,E_{k_N}$ cover $E$), and the result follows quickly. If $|E| = c < \infty$ and $N=1$, then the result follows quickly, and if $N \geq 2$, then $\mu(E) < 1 \leq \sum_{i=1}^N \mu(E_{k_i})$ because this is a sum of at least two numbers that are each no less than $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why are we allowed to assume the cover is increasing? In the text I'm using (Royden) to show countably monotone we let $E$ be some arbitrary set and $\{E_k\}_{k≥1}$ some arbitrary cover of E and show that $\mu(E) ≤ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)$. I'm assuming what you showed is sufficient, but I'm not seeing how to bridge the gap.

Comment: @Newman Actually I was just guessing at the meaning of "countably monotone". Since you've clarified the definition, I've updated my answer.